# How I switch fragment from another fragment on bottom navigtion view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I use Bottom navigation View [1.HomeFragment 2.DashboardFragment 3.ProfileFragment]. I want to navigate from HomeFragment to DashboardFragment.

Here is code I use, but it won't work, it close the application

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navigation_dashboard, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

And I used this method also is'nt work:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigation_dashboard, new DashboardFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Fragments, I highly recommend you use the Navigation Component.

It's easier to use, makes your code cleaner and is used in many top 1000 apps on Google PlayStore.
If you wish to read more [Android Developers Website](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation).

Comment: Thank you for sharing details about navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code:**

In Activity:

```
 b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigation_dashboard, new DashboardFragment(),"Dashboard").commit();
            }
        });
```

In Fragments:

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigation_dashboard, new DashboardFragment(),"Dashboard").commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I used this method already, It can't work, When I used this method the current fragment only appears unable to switch another fragment.

Comment: Edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BottomNavigationView then you have to implement setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener like this:

```
  bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_favorites:

                    break;
                case R.id.action_schedules:

                    break;
                case R.id.action_music:

                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

});

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadSajjadSaleem, but I want to switch navigation by Button (OnClickListener),I already implement the total bottom navigation view structure. If you know the navigation method by using button click please share to me.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use the Navigation Component.
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

```
  // Java language implementation
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

  // Kotlin
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

  // Feature module Support
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
```

Create a menu : res/menu/my_navigation_items.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/action_home"
          android:title="@string/menu_home"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_home" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_dashboard"
          android:title="@string/menu_dashboard"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_profile"
          android:title="@string/menu_profile"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile" />
 </menu>
```

and assign it as bottomNavigationView menu with **app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"**:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

And finaly the most important, use a navigation graph inside a androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This graph will automatically instantiate your fragments. you should create this in res/navigation/ :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_fragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:name="<yourpackage>.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_fragment"
        android:name="<yourpackage>.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/informations"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_report" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
        android:name="<yourpackage>.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/profile_layout" />
</navigation>
```